# Python - Easiest way to change numbers to words

Tags: python

I know that I can use `num2words`, but for some reason I just cant think of how to have the user input a number say "197" and it come out with "one nine seven" instead of One Hundred Ninety Seven". All the ones I have seen so far change it into the actual number they input, while I just need the exact numbers they input printed. Sorry for my lack of knowledge in Python, literally just getting started and a little confused. I am using this as a skeleton for it currently, but it can only print up to 9 as I am still learning.

```
import math

number = int(input("Enter number to print: "))

number_list = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]

if number <= 9:
    print(number_list[number].capitalize())
```

Comment: Forming a custom python dictionary is a bit new for me by far, but I see where this was going and the answer I got was this exactly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried map?

```
    input_number = input('Enter a number to print: ')
    number_strings = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                      'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
                      'eight', 'nine']

    output_list = list(map(lambda x: number_strings[int(x)], input_number))

    print(' '.join(output_list))
```

Comment: I haven't as I am reading up on mapping right now, but this was definitely the answer I was looking for. I really appreciate it. So does the lambda or map  basically take each int thats input and switch it out for the string?

Comment: the lambda is just an anonymous function (a function without declaration), you can declare a function such as number_converter(n) and return the number string. then pass the function to map. map takes each value in the iterable (individual characters of input_number) and pass it to the function and append the results to a map object. I just took the map object and converted it to a list, that's all :)

Comment: Nice answer, but no need to call `list()` on map - just `' '.join(map(...`

Comment: it's just to show how to convert map object to a list or a string

Answer (score 0):

With `number_list` defined as you have it above, you can do:

```
number = str(input("Enter number to print: "))

for digit in number:
    print(number_list[int(digit)], end=" ")
```

which prints the digits one at a time. The `end` parameter dictates that a space should be printed after each digit.